# iPhone SDK: pushViewController crashing

Tags: iphone

I am having problems with getting a detail view to load using pushViewController. At first, I thought pushViewController was not working. BUT, then I tried using a different view controller and it worked. I can tell from tracing that the problem view controller is never loaded at all. In other words, I tried to eliminate the possibility that there was some error in the view controller by NSLoging in that object and I never see anything.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

/*  
    NSLog(@"hsitkjsdfkljlkd");

    if (childController == nil)
        childController = [[salesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"salesView" bundle:nil];

    //NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:childController
                                         animated:YES];

 */

/*  

    //modal = blocking
    salesViewController *otherVC = [[salesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"salesView" bundle:nil];

    //must set sale type
    otherVC.strSaleType = @"Voice";

    [self presentModalViewController: otherVC animated:YES]; 

    //No close. By design, it is up to the otherVC to close itself  

    */

    //tipCalcViewController *detailViewController = [[tipCalcViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tipCalcView" bundle:nil];
    salesViewController *detailViewController = [[salesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"salesView" bundle:nil];
    // ...
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release]; 


}
```

Comment: do you see any error message in console on crash?

Comment: The above, plus, are you sure the nib name you've specified is correct?

Comment: No console messages. The name of the nib is correct too. How to troubleshoot?

Comment: FYI: as a matter of style, in Cocoa, class names always start with capital letters.

Comment: Can you share your salesViewController.h/.m and XIB file to me?

Answer (score 3):

Just Check the

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


}
```

of the `salesViewController`.

you are doing something wrong in this..

put the debugging point in the `viewWillAppear` and run it. you can get the error line..

Answer (score 0):

just try it......Surely it will work for u...

```
salesViewController *detailViewController = [[salesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"salesViewController" bundle:nil];

// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Also make sure you are giving the IBOutlet connection to UIView.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had several IBOutlets that I removed from the Header file and forgot to remove the connection to these non-existing outlets in Interface Builder. So removing the obsolete outlets fixed the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

*When you're pushing from ViewController1 to ViewController2 then the code will be used like this so try this code,*

```
ViewController2 *vw2=[[ViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vw2 animated:YES];
```

*The Above code may be written on Click event of button or on didSelect delegate of UITableView*